# How to use ECDiffieHellmanCng with OpenId in .Net 3.5?

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I need to get those parameters of OpenId protocol:

```
sd["openid.assoc_type"] = ???;
sd["openid.session_type"] = ???;
sd["openid.dh_modulus"] = ???;
sd["openid.dh_gen"] = ???;
sd["openid.dh_consumer_public"] = ???;
```

How can I get it using `ECDiffieHellmanCng` ? Is it real?

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, ECDiffieHellmanCng is *not* the Diffie-Hellman algorithm that OpenID uses.  DotNetOpenId doesn't use it (for that reason).

DotNetOpenId has it's own built-in implementation of the DH algorithm since it's not built into .NET.  And it should properly handle the openid.dh_modulus and openid.dh_gen parameters already.

What are you trying to do?